# Verilog - Getting a mismatch error trying to replicate output of another module

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to design a fifo that accepts a maximum of N=4 words and has a M=2 bit width of each word.
I first designed a 1 bit width word fifo and I'm trying to use it for the wider one. I'm having an issue debugging the line

```
single_fifo fArr[M-1:0]({M*{clk}},{M*{reset}},in,{M*{push}},{M*{pop}},out,full_string);
```

While getting the following error:

> ncelab: *E,PCAVDM (./fifo.v,85|27): Vector length of port connection expression (32) in array of instances does not match product of number of instances (2) and port length (1).
>      single_fifo fArrM-1:0;

My code has nothing that's 32 bits long so I'm quite confused by this error.

My code:

```
 module fifo(clk, reset, in, push, pop, out, full);
   parameter N=4; // determines the maximum number of words in queue.
   parameter M=2; // determines the bit-width of each word, stored in the queue.

   input clk, reset, push, pop;
   input [M-1:0] in;
   output [M-1:0] out;

   wire [M-1:0] full_string;
   output full;
   wire full;

   single_fifo fArr[M-1:0]({M*{clk}},{M*{reset}},in,{M*{push}},{M*{pop}},out,full_string);

   assign full=|full_string;

endmodule
```

I'll also add the list of ports for single_fifo in case it's required:

```
module single_fifo(clk,reset,in_bit,push,pop,out_bit,full);
   parameter N=4; // determines the maximum number of words in queue.
   input clk, reset, push, pop;
   input in_bit;
   output out_bit;

   reg [N-1:0] bit_list;
   reg [N-1:0] n; 
   reg out_bit;
   output full;
   reg full;
```

Sorry if my question seems noobish, I'm still new to verilog. Help will be appriciated!

Comment: `{M*{clk}` means multiplication of M by clk and the  32-bit wide result. you probably meant this `{M{clk}}` which is the replication operator with a 2-bit result.

Comment: Second time you help me today, you're a life saver! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you probably meant to use *replication* `{M{clk}}` instead of *multiplication* `{M*{clk}}`, there is no need for any of this with an array of instances. Verilog automatically replicates the signals you connect to an array of instances so you can just write

```
single_fifo fArr[M-1:0](clk,reset,in,push,pop,out,full_string);
```

P.S. I should know because I was responsible for added this feature to Verilog way back in 1990. 
See section *23.3.3.5 Unpacked array ports and arrays of instances* in the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM